# Python crashing when working with more than 300.000 records

Tags: python, pandas

I'm plotting a seaborn heatmap and for the dataset I'm retrieving records from MySQL. When I run the script it crashes with the following error:

> Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11:
>   SIGSEGV)

At first I thought it had to be in the data, as 300K records is not that much right? But ordering the dataset the other way around when selecting from the database I'm seeing the same behaviour: 300K records is fine, 310K records does cause a crash.

Secondly I tried disabling all the different things in the code to see what is causing the crash. As far as I can tell it's is the groupby that is causing the problem. Hard to be sure as other parts of the code won't work without the groupby, but disabling the merge and the pivot were no solution so it really seems to be the groupby.

Is there another way I should be doing the groupby? or perhaps splitting it or something?

My code:

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import rcParams

#mysql create engine and retrieve data and put in dataframe
engine = create_engine('mysql+mysqlconnector://[connection data]', echo=False)
connection = engine.connect()
query = connection.execute("SELECT * FROM ActivityRawData order by Time asc limit 0, 310000")
df = pd.DataFrame(query.fetchall())
df.columns = query.keys()

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'])
df.set_index('Date',inplace=True)

#round for the groupby
df = df.round(1)

#groupby HR and Speed
df = df.groupby(['HR','Speed']).count().reset_index()

#create continuous values and merge to fill up and make sure plot is continuous
dfY = pd.DataFrame({'HR':np.arange(min(df['HR']), max(df['HR']),1)})
dfX = pd.DataFrame({'Speed':np.arange(min(df['Speed']), max(df['Speed']),0.1)})
df = pd.merge(df,dfY, how='outer', on='HR')
df = pd.merge(df,dfX, how='outer', on='Speed')
df = df.round(1)

data = df.pivot("HR","Speed","Distance").sort_values(by=['HR'],ascending=False).drop(np.nan,axis=1).drop(np.nan,axis=0)

#######################
## Create the graph  ##
#######################

sns.set(style="white")
#plt.style.use('dark_background')
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,6))

ax=sns.heatmap(data,xticklabels="auto",ax = ax, robust=True, cmap='RdBu_r',cbar_kws={"shrink":.8, "label": "Count"})

#configure and set title
rcParams['axes.titlepad']=20
ax.set_title('Running Efficiency', fontsize=16, fontdict={})

#configure the x and y ticks
plt.xticks(fontsize="9", rotation=45)
plt.yticks(rotation=0, fontsize="10")
plt.ylabel("Average heart rate")
plt.xlabel("Average speed (m/s)")

#set labelsize of the colorbar
cbar = ax.collections[0].colorbar
cbar.ax.tick_params(labelsize=10)

plt.show()
```

And 100 rows of the data as example:

```
Alt     Cadence     Distance    HR  Lat     Lon     Speed   Time    
14.600000381469727  10  10670.7802734375    162 52.684949431568384  4.698166446760297   3.0510001182556152  2018-10-28 10:32:44 
14.399999618530273  10  10674.26953125  161 52.68491967581213   4.6981824561953545  3.181999921798706   2018-10-28 10:32:45 
14.199999809265135  10  10677.83984375  161 52.6848918478936    4.6982124634087095  3.23799991607666    2018-10-28 10:32:46 
14.199999809265135  10  10680.6103515625    161 52.68487055785953   4.6982402075082055  3.23799991607666    2018-10-28 10:32:47 
14.399999618530273  10  10684.169921875 161 52.68484013155103   4.698260156437755   3.125999927520752   2018-10-28 10:32:48 
14.399999618530273  10  10686.75    162 52.684817416593425  4.698268957436085   3.003999948501587   2018-10-28 10:32:49 
14.600000381469727  10  10689.4501953125    162 52.684792522341006  4.698286643251778   2.809000015258789   2018-10-28 10:32:50 
14.800000190734865  10  10691.58984375  162 52.68477332778274   4.698283877223731   2.7709999084472656  2018-10-28 10:32:51 
15  10  10693.3896484375    162 52.68475765362382   4.698276836425067   2.575000047683716   2018-10-28 10:32:52 
15.199999809265135  10  10695.9599609375    161 52.684735022485256  4.69826971180737    2.565999984741211   2018-10-28 10:32:53 
15.399999618530273  10  10699.419921875 161 52.684704847633846  4.698256468400358   2.743000030517578   2018-10-28 10:32:54 
15.600000381469727  10  10702.3095703125    160 52.68467886373401   4.698254121467472   3.032000064849853   2018-10-28 10:32:55 
15.800000190734865  10  10705.25    159 52.68465237691999   4.698256887495519   3.059999942779541   2018-10-28 10:32:56 
15.600000381469727  10  10708.400390625 158 52.684624129906304  4.698261078447104   3.0699999332427983  2018-10-28 10:32:57 
15.600000381469727  10  10711.990234375 158 52.68459185957909   4.698263006284833   3.1440000534057617  2018-10-28 10:32:58 
15.600000381469727  10  10715.240234375 157 52.68456269055605   4.698264850303532   3.3220000267028813  2018-10-28 10:32:59 
15.399999618530273  10  10717.919921875 157 52.68453855067492   4.698263173922896   3.3220000267028813  2018-10-28 10:33:00 
15.199999809265135  10  10720.75    157 52.68451306968928   4.698261916637421   3.088000059127808   2018-10-28 10:33:01 
15  10  10723.580078125 157 52.684487337246544  4.698260743170977   2.994999885559082   2018-10-28 10:33:02 
14.800000190734865  10  10726.4599609375    157 52.684461520984776  4.698255965486169   3.0789999961853027  2018-10-28 10:33:03 
14.600000381469727  10  10729.1396484375    157 52.684436459094286  4.698256803676487   3.032000064849853   2018-10-28 10:33:04 
14.600000381469727  10  10731.75    158 52.68441391177476   4.698244817554952   3.032000064849853   2018-10-28 10:33:05 
14.600000381469727  10  10733.66015625  158 52.68439555540681   4.698238614946604   2.7809998989105225  2018-10-28 10:33:06 
14.800000190734865  10  10736.2001953125    160 52.68437401391565   4.698225958272816   2.743000030517578   2018-10-28 10:33:07 
14.800000190734865  10  10739.48046875  161 52.684344844892614  4.698215480893849   2.743000030517578   2018-10-28 10:33:08 
14.800000190734865  10  10742.3095703125    161 52.68431944772601   4.698211960494518   2.874000072479248   2018-10-28 10:33:09 
15  10  10744.7001953125    162 52.684298409149044  4.698218666017056   2.874000072479248   2018-10-28 10:33:10 
15  10  10747.0595703125    161 52.6842768676579    4.698222856968642   2.7249999046325684  2018-10-28 10:33:11 
15.199999809265135  10  10749.6103515625    161 52.68425406888127   4.698230735957623   2.63100004196167    2018-10-28 10:33:12 
15.199999809265135  10  10752.58984375  160 52.68422774970532   4.698239956051111   2.63100004196167    2018-10-28 10:33:13 
15.199999809265135  10  10755.8896484375    160 52.68420411273837   4.6982696279883385  2.8929998874664307  2018-10-28 10:33:14 
15.199999809265135  10  10758.7099609375    158 52.684180224314325  4.698285050690174   2.8929998874664307  2018-10-28 10:33:15 
15.199999809265135  10  10761.25    157 52.68415843136609   4.698297204449774   2.882999897003174   2018-10-28 10:33:16 
15.199999809265135  10  10763.73046875  157 52.684141919016845  4.698338359594344   2.882999897003174   2018-10-28 10:33:17 
15.199999809265135  10  10766.2001953125    157 52.684122556820505  4.6983565483242264  2.82699990272522    2018-10-28 10:33:18 
15.199999809265135  10  10769.3896484375    157 52.68409498035908   4.698371049016714   2.8929998874664307  2018-10-28 10:33:19 
15  10  10772   157 52.6840767916292    4.698397284373642   2.7809998989105225  2018-10-28 10:33:20 
15  10  10774.4697265625    157 52.68405927345157   4.698419999331237   2.7809998989105225  2018-10-28 10:33:21 
14.800000190734865  10  10776.650390625 157 52.68404150381684   4.698434248566628   2.650000095367432   2018-10-28 10:33:22 
14.800000190734865  10  10778.759765625 156 52.684029182419174  4.698461489751934   2.565999984741211   2018-10-28 10:33:23 
14.800000190734865  10  10781.3095703125    156 52.6840139273554    4.69849057495594    2.556999921798706   2018-10-28 10:33:24 
14.800000190734865  10  10783.349609375 156 52.68400403670967   4.698517145588994   2.500999927520752   2018-10-28 10:33:25 
14.800000190734865  10  10786.0703125   156 52.68399615772069   4.6985556185245505  2.556999921798706   2018-10-28 10:33:26 
14.800000190734865  10  10788.33984375  157 52.683991966769106  4.698589397594334   2.565999984741211   2018-10-28 10:33:27 
14.800000190734865  10  10791.7099609375    157 52.68398568034172   4.698638264089824   2.63100004196167    2018-10-28 10:33:28 
14.600000381469727  10  10794.7900390625    158 52.68397461622954   4.6986801736056805  3.1070001125335693  2018-10-28 10:33:29 
14.800000190734865  10  10798.6103515625    158 52.683963384479284  4.698733650147915   3.125999927520752   2018-10-28 10:33:30 
14.800000190734865  10  10801.5498046875    159 52.6839523203671    4.698774134740233   3.125999927520752   2018-10-28 10:33:31 
15  10  10804.6298828125    159 52.683931533247225  4.6988044772297135  3.032000064849853   2018-10-28 10:33:32 
15.199999809265135  10  10807.830078125 159 52.68390789628029   4.698831299319863   2.994999885559082   2018-10-28 10:33:33 
15.199999809265135  10  10811.2197265625    159 52.68388685770332   4.698868095874786   2.986000061035156   2018-10-28 10:33:34 
15.399999618530273  10  10813.7998046875    159 52.683868166059256  4.698890643194319   2.9210000038146973  2018-10-28 10:33:35 
15.399999618530273  10  10816.8798828125    159 52.683849222958095  4.6989243384450665  2.874000072479248   2018-10-28 10:33:36 
15.600000381469727  10  10819.5498046875    159 52.683832375332706  4.698952585458756   2.7709999084472656  2018-10-28 10:33:37 
15.800000190734865  10  10821.490234375 159 52.68381795845925   4.698968846350908   2.5850000381469727  2018-10-28 10:33:38 
16  10  10824.08984375  159 52.683800524100654  4.698995668441056   2.509999990463257   2018-10-28 10:33:39 
16.200000762939453  10  10826.419921875 160 52.68378459848464   4.699018215760589   2.4820001125335693  2018-10-28 10:33:40 
16.200000762939453  10  10828.66015625  161 52.68376825377345   4.6990391705185175  2.4260001182556152  2018-10-28 10:33:41 
16.399999618530273  10  10832.169921875 161 52.683745371177785  4.699077475816011   2.4260001182556152  2018-10-28 10:33:42 
16.399999618530273  10  10834.919921875 162 52.683722991496325  4.699094910174608   2.7709999084472656  2018-10-28 10:33:43 
16.399999618530273  10  10837.58984375  162 52.683701617643244  4.6991133503615865  2.818000078201294   2018-10-28 10:33:44 
16.399999618530273  10  10840.7900390625    162 52.68367672339082   4.699138244614005   2.818000078201294   2018-10-28 10:33:45 
16.399999618530273  10  10843.23046875  162 52.683656355366104  4.6991525776684275  2.818000078201294   2018-10-28 10:33:46 
16.200000762939453  10  10845.6103515625    161 52.683634394779794  4.699170682579278   2.6689999103546143  2018-10-28 10:33:47 
16.200000762939453  10  10848.51953125  161 52.68360824324191   4.699174789711833   2.6689999103546143  2018-10-28 10:33:48 
16  10  10851.9404296875    161 52.68357764929533   4.699184009805323   2.845999956130981   2018-10-28 10:33:49 
15.600000381469727  10  10854.2802734375    160 52.683556862175465  4.6991913858801135  2.845999956130981   2018-10-28 10:33:50 
15.399999618530273  10  10857.4599609375    160 52.68352878279985   4.699200941249729   2.9670000076293945  2018-10-28 10:33:51 
15  10  10859.7998046875    160 52.683508163318045  4.699207479134202   2.697000026702881   2018-10-28 10:33:52 
14.800000190734865  10  10862   159 52.68348846584559   4.699210580438376   2.697000026702881   2018-10-28 10:33:53 
14.600000381469727  10  10864.5302734375    158 52.68346566706896   4.699210664257407   2.697000026702881   2018-10-28 10:33:54 
14.199999809265135  10  10867.9296875   158 52.68343515694141   4.699207982048391   2.7809998989105225  2018-10-28 10:33:55 
14  10  10870.849609375 157 52.683409340679646  4.6991996839642525  2.9019999504089355  2018-10-28 10:33:56 
13.800000190734865  10  10873.7802734375    157 52.683384278789156  4.699186272919178   2.9479999542236333  2018-10-28 10:33:57 
13.600000381469727  10  10876.4501953125    156 52.68336148001254   4.699174119159579   2.9019999504089355  2018-10-28 10:33:58 
13.600000381469727  10  10878.7197265625    156 52.683341531082995  4.699167162179948   2.809000015258789   2018-10-28 10:33:59 
13.600000381469727  10  10880.8603515625    156 52.68332208506764   4.699161043390632   2.6410000324249268  2018-10-28 10:34:00 
13.399999618530273  10  10884.25    156 52.68329232931137   4.6991495601832876  2.6410000324249268  2018-10-28 10:34:01 
13.399999618530273  10  10887.48046875  157 52.683263579383485  4.69914679415524    2.9210000038146973  2018-10-28 10:34:02 
13.600000381469727  10  10890.6201171875    157 52.683235080912716  4.699149392545222   2.9210000038146973  2018-10-28 10:34:03 
13.600000381469727  10  10893.5595703125    157 52.683206498622894  4.699148051440716   2.836999893188477   2018-10-28 10:34:04 
13.600000381469727  10  10895.9404296875    157 52.68318470567465   4.699138579890132   2.76200008392334    2018-10-28 10:34:05 
13.600000381469727  10  10897.509765625 157 52.683173390105374  4.699124582111836   2.61299991607666    2018-10-28 10:34:06 
13.600000381469727  10  10899.580078125 157 52.6831560395658    4.6991130989044905  2.2950000762939453  2018-10-28 10:34:07 
13.600000381469727  10  10901.830078125 157 52.683137599378824  4.699097340926529   2.2950000762939453  2018-10-28 10:34:08 
13.600000381469727  10  10904.5 157 52.683116644620895  4.699075799435377   2.434999942779541   2018-10-28 10:34:09 
13.600000381469727  10  10906.849609375 158 52.68309887498617   4.6990533359348765  2.5190000534057617  2018-10-28 10:34:10 
13.600000381469727  10  10909.169921875 159 52.68308160826564   4.6990314591676 2.5190000534057617  2018-10-28 10:34:11 
13.600000381469727  10  10911.740234375 160 52.68306417390704   4.699004888534546   2.5290000438690186  2018-10-28 10:34:12 
13.600000381469727  10  10915.080078125 160 52.683039866387844  4.698975635692476   2.556999921798706   2018-10-28 10:34:13 
13.800000190734865  10  10918.4404296875    161 52.683017402887344  4.6989419404417285  2.9110000133514404  2018-10-28 10:34:14 
13.800000190734865  10  10922.2099609375    160 52.68299250863493   4.698903635144233   2.938999891281128   2018-10-28 10:34:15 
14  10  10925.490234375 160 52.68297281116247   4.6988669224083415  3.0510001182556152  2018-10-28 10:34:16 
14.199999809265135  10  10928.6103515625    159 52.682955795899026  4.698829958215357   3.059999942779541   2018-10-28 10:34:17 
14.199999809265135  10  10931.6796875   158 52.682941798120744  4.698789473623037   2.9670000076293945  2018-10-28 10:34:18 
14.399999618530273  10  10933.8095703125    158 52.682930901646614  4.6987626515328875  2.865000009536743   2018-10-28 10:34:19 
14.399999618530273  10  10936.4404296875    158 52.68291547894478   4.698730967938901   2.6589999198913574  2018-10-28 10:34:20 
14.399999618530273  10  10938.7099609375    158 52.68290064297617   4.698704229667784   2.565999984741211   2018-10-28 10:34:21 
14.600000381469727  10  10940.5400390625    158 52.68288924358786   4.698678581044078   2.5380001068115234  2018-10-28 10:34:22 
14.800000190734865  10  10942.7197265625    159 52.6828832924366    4.698647148907185   2.4260001182556152  2018-10-28 10:34:23
```

Comment: what are the `dtypes` of the df that contains the query results?

Comment: print(df.dtypes) gives:
Alt                float64
Cadence            float64
Distance           float64
HR                 float64
Lat                float64
Lon                float64
Speed              float64
Time        datetime64[ns]
dtype: object